# Is there a built-in way to retrieve a PHP array element such that it is removed from the array?

Tags: php, arrays

Is there a built-in way to retrieve a PHP array element such that it is removed from the array? Similar to [`array_pop()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-pop.php), but on a specific index? For example:

```
<?php
$array = [
    'foo' => 123,
    'bar' => 456,
    'baz' => 789
];

$bar = array_get_and_remove($array, 'bar');

/* Outputs:
 * $bar = 456,
 * $array = ['foo' => 123, 'baz' => 789]
*/
```

Comment: You can use `array_splice()`

Comment: http://php.net/array_splice

Comment: `array_splice()` only works for numeric indices?

Comment: Well it works with the offset of the key, so if you have a string key you just search for it to get the offset with `array_search()`.

Comment: Had to be easier than `array_splice()` :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$element = $array[$key];
unset($array[$key]);
```

So to make your function (be sure to use a reference `&`):

```
function array_get_and_remove(&$array, $key);
    $element = $array[$key];
    unset($array[$key]);
    return $element;
}
```

Then:

```
$bar = array_get_and_remove($array, 'bar');
```

Comment: Well damn, I overthunk mine!

Answer (score 2):

There is no one function built-in way.  *Aammad Ullah* got right to it while I overthunk it, but here's a simple way. `$result` will contain `'bar' => 456` and it will be removed from `$array`:

```
$array = array_diff_key($array, $result = ['bar' => $array['bar']]);
```

- Assign `'bar' => $array['bar']` array to `$result`
- Compute difference of array and `$result`

Using `array_splice()`:

```
$result = array_splice($array, array_search('bar', array_keys($array), true), 1);
```

- Get an array of the string keys `array_keys()`
- Search that array for `bar` returning the numeric key/offset `array_search()`
- Use that offset and length of `1` to remove that element and return it `array_splice()`

To get just the value use something like `current()`:

```
$result = current(array_splice($array, array_search('bar', array_keys($array), true), 1));
```

Comment: I think you want to use `array_diff_key()`, so it gets the difference based on the key not on the value. Also no `array_column()` solution? I'm disappointed :P

Comment: Good point.  It works either way so long as the value is unique but edited, because it probably won't be.  I could do `array_column()` but would not make much sense ;-)